# Blazor Hot Reload Debugging Using VSCode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, blazor

I want to debug with hot reload enabled using VSCode. I keep getting this error after I made some changes:

> BadImageFormatException: Bad IL range. OTPHub.Pages.Counter..ctor()
>
> TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
> an invocation. System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(bool
> publicOnly, bool wrapExceptions)

It seems that there is a problem with the hot reloaded built assembly.

Here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "program": "dotnet",
      "args": [
        "watch",
        "--project",
        ".",
        "--verbose"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/OTPHub",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "openExternally",
        "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
      },
      "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "sourceFileMap": {
        "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Attach",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach"
    }
  ]
}
```

Should change something from this `launch.json` setting? How can I debug it with hot reload enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Basically removed `cwd` and added specific project file path as I had multiple projects in my workspace.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "program": "dotnet",
      "args": [
        "watch",
        "--project",
        "./Project/Project.csproj", //IMPORTANT: give .csproj file path relative to workspace root
        "--verbose"
      ],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "openExternally",
        "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
      },
      "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "sourceFileMap": {
        "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Attach",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach"
    }
  ]
}
```

Inspiration: [@MrC aka Shaun Curtis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73571698/148271)

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your *launch.json* over the one in a clean build project with one change to *cwd* (removed /OTPHub).  It all works, so your problem is elsewhere.

Here's my steps:

1. Create a directory
2. Start VS in the directory
3. `dotnet new blazorserver`
4. `dotnet watch`.
5. `Ctrl-C`.
6. Cut and paste your config into *launch.json*
7. `dotnet watch`.
8. Change some text in *Index*.

Comment: this is good but how to hit the breakpoint this way?

Comment: Breakpoint is empty circle with grey border instead of circle with solid brown fill.